# How to create Wordpress' permalinks after creating a custom post type?

Tags: wordpress, custom-post-type, permalinks

I just created a custom post type called products in Wordpress. When I select plain permalinks, the links work fine. When I select any other permalink, the URL cannot be found.

For instance, `http://localhost/TheGrind/?products=gopro-hero6-black` is my permalink with the plain option selected. And `http://localhost/TheGrind/product/gopro-hero6-black/`is the permalink that I'm looking to use for my posts. I get a

```
 Not Found
    The requested URL /TheGrind/product/gopro-hero6-black/ was not found on this server.
```

The question is how can I get this type of URL to work when I create a custom post type in Wordpress.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Just save the new option of permalink again and that will flush the old rewrite rules.

Comment: How do you save the new option? I tried the flush_rewrite_rules(); but that didn't work.

Comment: Check if in this screen (permalinks) is there any error messages for the .htaccess, maybe you should check your permissions for this file.

Comment: Thanks for all your help. I managed to get it to work after modifying the httpd.config file in Apache. Now all my links are perfect as I anticipated. The problem was to AllowOverride All to be set. Now when I'm in Wordpress I can set the .htaccess files for each website. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

You could try adding

```
flush_rewrite_rules();
```

after you have called

```
register_post_type();
```

That has fixed the issue for me in the past.

If it does work for you, you can then remove the "flush_rewrite_rules();" as WordPress states it is an expensive operation.

https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/flush_rewrite_rules